# Optimising multiple nested `for` loops in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am preparing a file for upload to a database. The data is comprised of multiple tables in a hierarchy, with the tables in general being larger (many more rows) lower in the hierarchy. Tables are a mix of different data types and have different numbers of columns.

Each row of each table is linked via an ID number to a row in the table above it in the hierarchy - essentially the row number (though the converse is not necessarily true; not every row in a table is necessarily linked to from rows in tables below it in the hierarchy).

The structure of the upload file is like this: the first row of the highest table (say A), then the row of the next table (B) which links to it, then the row of C which links to B, then row in D linked to C, etc. If no lower link is found it stays at that level in the hierarchy and goes to the next row in that table and continues down from there. Once there are no more links to the relevant row of the table above, it goes up a level and goes to the next row of *that* table. No row is ever repeated, so the `nrow` of the final table is the sum of `nrow` of all tables. Hopefully this (and following example) makes sense.

I am using the following nested `for` loops to build the output, but it is extremely slow. The actual data is 8 or 9 nested tables with thousands of rows (the final table is 75K rows and it takes about 10-15 mins to run on my Apple Silicon MBP).

How can I optimise this or do it better? I have tried using `apply` functions, but really struggling with how to feed the output from the function environment to the iteration above and making the final table.

Or is there a way of using `dplyr` style joins? Or `data.table` syntax? Or a way of extracting a master index of which rows in which order?

I am not super experienced with databases, so maybe this is a common structure and there are other packages which may do something like this?

```
# Create some tables
tableA <- data.frame(Table = "A",
                     A.id = 1:3,
                     A.link.up = NA, # because it's the top table
                     A.data1 = c(10,20,20),
                     A.data2 = c("text", "moretext", "othertext"))

tableB <- data.frame(Table = "B",
                     B.id = 1:6,
                     B.link.up = c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
                     B.data1 = c("text", "difftext", "wtext", "xtext", "ytext", "ztext"),
                     B.data2 = "2023-02-09",
                     B.data3 = 1001:1006,
                     B.data4 = 55:60)

tableC <- data.frame(Table = "C",
                     C.id = 1:10,
                     C.link.up = c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,6,6),
                     C.data1 = 501:510,
                     C.data2 = "blah",
                     C.data3 = "zzz")

# Set up final output table
final_table <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = 7))
names(final_table) <- c("Originating.Table", "Row.id", "Link.upwards",
                        "various", "different", "data", "formats")

# A
for(a in 1:nrow(tableA)) { # for every row in A
  A.row <- tableA[a,]      # extract row
  final_table[nrow(final_table)+1,1:length(A.row)] <- A.row # Copy row to next row of final table
  A.id <- tableA$A.id[a]   # get that row id
  B.sub <- tableB[which(tableB$B.link.up == A.id),] # Subset rows in B that link to that row in A
  # B
  for(b in 1:nrow(B.sub)) { # for every row in this SUBSET of B
    B.row <- B.sub[b,]      # extract that row
    final_table[nrow(final_table)+1,1:length(B.row)] <- B.row # Copy to final table
    B.id <- B.sub$B.id[b]   # get that row id
    C.sub <- tableC[which(tableC$C.link.up == B.id),] # Subset rows in C that link to that row in B
    # C
    if(nrow(C.sub) > 0) { # because not every row in every table is linked to from lower tables
      for(c in 1:nrow(C.sub)) {
        C.row <- C.sub[c,]
        final_table[nrow(final_table)+1,1:length(C.row)] <- C.row
        # C.id <- tableC$C.id[c] # don't need - only required for subsetting further lower tables
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A couple of notes:

- Yes I know the final iteration (for tableC) is redundant - i could just copy the subset straight to the final table. I've left it to give an idea of how deep the rabbithole can go.
- As i said the tables have different number of columns so `rbind` does not work (as far as i could tell), hence setting up the final table df and awkward copying to it in the loops.
- Yes, nothing in C links to B5; every row links upwards, but not every row links downwards
- The linking ID numbers are not necessarily in numerical order as in this example - they may link to *any* row of the table above them. Hasn't caused me an issue though.

Comment: At first glance, it's not obvious to me what calculation / manipulation is required here besides renaming the columns to be consistent (where they're in common) and using `dplyr::bind_rows()`. Is the task to sort the rows based on links?

Comment: Where do you define the dataframe tree? Are the row counts of the parent dataframes unique or could tableC be child of any other table which happens to also have six rows to link up to?

Comment: @JonSpring  No columns are in common. I tried to explain it as best i could. Maybe i should have used 'parent-child' terminology.  It is maybe easier to think of coming upwards. Rows in Table C have a parent in B, which have a parent in A. One parent can have many children. The final table should have every child row or group of 'sibling rows' directly underneath it's parent.

Comment: @I_O I don't understand your question. It's a simple hierarchy A above B above C (above D,E,F etc...) No, rows in C have their parent in B not any other table.  Number or rows in any table is not important.

Comment: @jblood94 Well thanks for taking the time to point that out. Really gets to the point.

Comment: Sorry hokeybot, haven't looked carefully enough: the parent data is part of the column name. I'd thought about recursively traversing the dataframe hierarchy and presumed identical column names across the dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these should get what you're after much faster.

### Option 1

First some pre-processing:

```
library(data.table)

# column names of final output
nms <- c("Originating.Table", "Row.id", "Link.upwards",
         "various", "different", "data", "formats")

# create a list of tables ordered hierarchically
tables <- list(tableA = tableA, tableB = tableB, tableC = tableC)
# possibly: tables <- do.call("list", mget(ls(pattern = "table")))
# create a list of tables containing the hierarchical positioning
dts <- vector("list", length(tables))
dts[[1]] <- as.data.table(
  cbind(
    1:nrow(tables[[1]]),
    matrix(0L, nrow(tables[[1]]), length(tables) - 1L)
  )
)
# rename the table according to the final output
setnames(tables[[1]], nms[1:ncol(tables[[1]])])

for (i in 2:length(dts)) {
  # assuming the `link.up` column is always third, copy the positioning of the
  # next table up in the hierarchy
  dts[[i]] <- dts[[i - 1L]][tables[[i]][,3]]
  # the positioning for this level in the hierarchy
  dts[[i]][[i]] <- 1:nrow(tables[[i]])
  # rename the table according to the final output
  setnames(tables[[i]], nms[1:ncol(tables[[i]])])
}
```

Final table:

```
# bind the tables, filling with NA, then reorder based on the hierarchy
# ordering using `dts`
rbindlist(tables, fill = TRUE)[setorder(rbindlist(dts)[,r := .I])$r]
#>     Originating.Table Row.id Link.upwards  various  different data formats
#>  1:                 A      1           NA       10       text <NA>      NA
#>  2:                 B      1            1     text 2023-02-09 1001      55
#>  3:                 C      1            1      501       blah  zzz      NA
#>  4:                 B      2            1 difftext 2023-02-09 1002      56
#>  5:                 C      2            2      502       blah  zzz      NA
#>  6:                 C      3            2      503       blah  zzz      NA
#>  7:                 A      2           NA       20   moretext <NA>      NA
#>  8:                 B      3            2    wtext 2023-02-09 1003      57
#>  9:                 C      4            3      504       blah  zzz      NA
#> 10:                 B      4            2    xtext 2023-02-09 1004      58
#> 11:                 C      5            4      505       blah  zzz      NA
#> 12:                 C      6            4      506       blah  zzz      NA
#> 13:                 C      7            4      507       blah  zzz      NA
#> 14:                 C      8            4      508       blah  zzz      NA
#> 15:                 B      5            2    ytext 2023-02-09 1005      59
#> 16:                 A      3           NA       20  othertext <NA>      NA
#> 17:                 B      6            3    ztext 2023-02-09 1006      60
#> 18:                 C      9            6      509       blah  zzz      NA
#> 19:                 C     10            6      510       blah  zzz      NA
```

### Option 2

Probably slower, but should be more memory-efficient.

Pre-processing:

```
# column names of final output
nms <- c("Originating.Table", "Row.id", "Link.upwards",
         "various", "different", "data", "formats")

# create a list of tables ordered hierarchically
tables <- lapply(
  mget(ls(pattern = "table")), \(x) setnames(setDT(x), nms[1:ncol(x)])
)

# temporarily change `Link.upwards` for the first table
tables[[1]][,Link.upwards := as.list(Row.id)]

i <- unique(
  unlist(
    setDT(
      Reduce(
        \(x, y) {
          y[
            x,
            .(
              Row.id = Row.id,
              Link.upwards = as.list(
                as.data.frame(rbind(as.data.frame(i.Link.upwards), Row.id))
              )
            ), on = .(Link.upwards = Row.id), nomatch = NA
          ]
        },
        tables
      )[[2]]
    ) + c(0L, cumsum(sapply(tables[-length(tables)], nrow))),
    1, 0
  )
)

# change `Link.upwards` back to NA for the first table
tables[[1]][[3]] <- NA
```

Final table:

```
rbindlist(tables, fill = TRUE)[i[!is.na(i)]]
#>     Originating.Table Row.id Link.upwards  various  different data formats
#>  1:                 A      1           NA       10       text <NA>      NA
#>  2:                 B      1            1     text 2023-02-09 1001      55
#>  3:                 C      1            1      501       blah  zzz      NA
#>  4:                 B      2            1 difftext 2023-02-09 1002      56
#>  5:                 C      2            2      502       blah  zzz      NA
#>  6:                 C      3            2      503       blah  zzz      NA
#>  7:                 A      2           NA       20   moretext <NA>      NA
#>  8:                 B      3            2    wtext 2023-02-09 1003      57
#>  9:                 C      4            3      504       blah  zzz      NA
#> 10:                 B      4            2    xtext 2023-02-09 1004      58
#> 11:                 C      5            4      505       blah  zzz      NA
#> 12:                 C      6            4      506       blah  zzz      NA
#> 13:                 C      7            4      507       blah  zzz      NA
#> 14:                 C      8            4      508       blah  zzz      NA
#> 15:                 B      5            2    ytext 2023-02-09 1005      59
#> 16:                 A      3           NA       20  othertext <NA>      NA
#> 17:                 B      6            3    ztext 2023-02-09 1006      60
#> 18:                 C      9            6      509       blah  zzz      NA
#> 19:                 C     10            6      510       blah  zzz      NA
```

Comment: Thank you. This is incredibly helpful. Seems to work really well and definitely quicker. It will take me a while to properly understand it and use it on the actual data. There is an additional wrinkle in that one of the lower tables has parent-child row *within* it, but i will work womething out!

Comment: I don't see a way for a table to reference itself with the current format, but if you can put in an example, maybe it will be a simple addition. Also, see the updated answer for an even faster solution.

Comment: I think I will be able to just split it into two separate tables. May be some tidying after but should work. Thanks for the update. What is the logic in using these huge integers?

Comment: The logic was to add smaller and smaller increments as we go deeper into the hierarchy to ensure that the values added to pos from the higher levels dominate the values added lower down, but a quick test shows that this will quickly run into precision problems. I'm going to revert.

Comment: What perfect timing. I was just testing with real data and running into some weird inconsistent issues comparing outputs of my method vs yours. Just came back to this thread to copy your initial code to try it instead!  Indeed it seems to be working now to output the identical results. Just tried it on a subset of my data (creating a 21000 row table) and the time difference is 77s vs 0.1s.

Comment: 6 minutes vs 0.1s for 8 nested tables to a 44K row output. That is certainly quick enough. I haven't tried your revised option 2, but thanks for going through it again.